# Network Computers Not Showing up

Tags: 11.10, networking, samba

Alright, 3 machines running, two using Ubuntu 11.10 and one on Mac OS X.

On the two Ubuntu machines, both have samba installed and configured on the same workgroup, "HOME".

On machine 1, I can see all networked machines. On machine 2, I can only see the Mac OS X machine. It doesn't show the other Ubuntu machine.

What am I missing on machine 2 to see all networked computers?

Any suggestions are welcome. I'm pretty much stumped.

Comment: To follow up on some observations, if I go to Network and press Ctrl + L and type in the following:

smb://192.168.1.203, I can connect to machine 1.

But when clicking on the homes folder, it says unable to mount location.

Comment: Can you add the smb.conf files for each pc?

Comment: Sure, is there any easy way of posting it? The config file is rather large, with alot of stuff commented out, you want all of it?

Comment: I'm just wondering how you configured the workgroup, etc. Try comparing the smb.conf files between machine 1 and machine 2. It may reveal the issue.

Comment: Well the workgroup on both configs are set to the same thing. Unless there are other options I should include though.

Comment: try booting each pc from a livecd and see if everything in the network can see each other :-) If so, that means something set in the configs is hindering you from seeing everything.

Comment: Have you tried diffing the config files?

Comment: Are you using different user names on the different machines?

Comment: No, same usernames on all machines...

Comment: Is this related to Bonjour and ZeroConf networking? Check that Avahi is running. You might check to see if it is running on both systems (checking for it running on one and not the other). Then again, this may be why the Mac shows up and the other doesn't. Did you compare the /etc/samba/smb.conf files on both machines?

Comment: Can you access the computers you don't see in the network with smb://computer-name/ from Nautilus (use Ctrl+L to manually type the path)?

Comment: Put the smb.conf files and /etc/hosts files onto ubuntu pastebin (http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and link them here. There's also something you can run (I forget the name) to strip the comments from smb.conf - that speeds it up immensely. Also check your nmbd (that does what WINS does on a Windows network), that's what aids name resolution. Also check UIDs are matched, though it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the machine that is not visible, try doing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> then `smb://localhost`. You can connect to itself.

Also, make sure that the `smb` service is running on the machine that you can't see.

It might also be worth seeing if you have a firewall issue, turn off the firewalls on your machines to see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For Samba/CIFS shares to be discoverable for all clients it is common that one of the servers acts as a WINS server. However if both are trying to be the master it might cause this kind of behaviour.

Also iptables must be off or you should allow:
137/UDP
138/UDP
139/UDP
445/TCP

These are the Samba/CIFS ports.

Kind regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1):

I added these lines:

```
os level = 99
wins support = yes
name resolve order = wins lmhosts hosts bcast
domain master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

to my global samba configuration all the computers in my network popped right up in windows network.

found the info here:

http://whereofwecannotspeak.wordpress.com/2007/10/24/samba-as-a-wins-server-in-a-windows-peer-network/