# I can only see one computer in the network, why is that?

Tags: networking

I've installed Ubuntu on one machine and would like to connect to other Windows computers in the same network. On a Windows comnputer I can see several machines but on my Ubuntu computer I can only see one, why is that?

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102384/network-computers-not-showing-up. Check this !

Comment: @kostandinangjellari That's not the problem here because this is **one** Ubuntu machine and **several Windows** computers. not the same question.

Comment: When you say see, you probably mean that you can see win sharing or you can ping/telnet/ssh them? If you talk about win sharing try with `sudo smbtree` to see all pc on lan. Maybe are pc in different workgroup ...